# Should 'do' after 'than' be inverted in this sentence?

Tags: word-order, ellipsis, comparative-constructions, subject-auxiliary-inversion

That is, ***Strangers stand further apart than acquaintances do*** is ungrammatical? I have often encountered inverted clauses after ***than***, ***as***, ***so*** in comparatives, so the sentence above seems - at least to me - to be ungrammatical.

> Distance is a reliable indicator of the relationship between two
> people. ***Strangers stand further apart than do acquaintances***,
> acquaintances stand further apart than friends, and friends stand
> further apart than romantic partners.

[Social Psychology: Exploring the Dynamics of Human Experience](https://books.google.co.kr/books?id=cuCsDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA203&lpg=PA203&dq=acquaintances%20stand%20further%20apart%20than%20friends,%20and%20friends%20stand%20further%20apart%20than%20romantic%20partners.%20Sometimes,%20of%20course,%20these%20rules%20are%20violated.%20Recall%20the%20last%20time%20you%20rode%2020%20stories%20in%20an%20elevator%20packed%20with%20total%20strangers.&source=bl&ots=_h_8I6OBbB&sig=ACfU3U1WCZYBply8G3Ckk4oh-jVsk1hvTw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj6_Jze4IX-AhU4mlYBHTaJB-AQ6AF6BAgeEAM#v=onepage&q=acquaintances%20stand%20further%20apart%20than%20friends%2C%20and%20friends%20stand%20further%20apart%20than%20romantic%20partners.%20Sometimes%2C%20of%20course%2C%20these%20rules%20are%20violated.%20Recall%20the%20last%20time%20you%20rode%2020%20stories%20in%20an%20elevator%20packed%20with%20total%20strangers.&f=false)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Repeating the verb in a comparison](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/89378/repeating-the-verb-in-a-comparison)

Comment: See also ["If extraversion is so much more beneficial ... than **is introversion**" - why not "than **introversion is**"?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/322486/). It's confusing that the example sentence refers to ***introversion*** (looking inward), because it's really about the subject/verb ***inversion*** (reverse position) in constructions like *If extraversion is so much more beneficial ... than **is introversion**, then...* (a "literary" inversion of the normal sequence *... than **introversion is***).

Comment: Does the suggested duplicate address the _than noun do / than do noun_ inversion?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey: It could be *any* verb - the point is it's "inversion", which is syntactically fine. But in conversational contexts, most of us probably wouldn't include any verb after ***than*** - just ***Strangers stand further apart than acquaintances*** is fine. And nobody wants to go the whole hog with ***Strangers stand further apart than acquaintances stand apart***.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["If extraversion is so much more beneficial ... than is introversion" - why not "than introversion is"?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/322486/if-extraversion-is-so-much-more-beneficial-than-is-introversion-why-not)